# How to calculate billing hours of employee in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in a work book, sheet 1 & sheet 2. In sheet 1 I have the list of employee id's:

[image]

In sheet 2 I have the billing details of employees where an employee can bill in different categories of which he can fill total of more than 40 hours.

[image]

I want to search the EMPID from sheet 1 EX:123 in Sheet 2. We can ignore Nonbillable in billing bucket column of an employee and sum the rest of the Billing bucket values.

Here for 123 EMPID total hours = Return to service(24)+Administration(8) =32 I have print this in sheet 1. total billable hours column.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Billingreport()
Billing = 0
Dim rng As Range
Dim account As String
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 20
For j = i To 20
If Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) Then
'& sheet2(j,2)! = "Nonbillable"
Billing = Billing + Sheet2(j, 3).Value
Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Billing.Value
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You not use `SUMIF`? If this needs to be VBA, you can just apply the `SUMIF` to the range. No need to loop here

Comment: I am getting the Error "Object doesn't support this property or method". Can any one please help me to correct the code.

Comment: Where are `Sheet2` and `Sheet1` defined? Those should be declared as worksheets and then set using `Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tables start with headers in respective sheets, you can simply enter following SUMIFS function in "B2" and copy it down

`=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!B:B,"<>Nonbillable")`

But since you are asking VBA ..

```
Sub Macro2()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B4").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C3:C3,Sheet2!C1:C1,RC[-1],Sheet2!C2:C2,""<>Nonbillable"")"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate
    'you can add the following line to convert the formula to value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B4").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Naresh Bhople . You saved lot of my efforts and time .It worked like a charm